# Browser's mDNS strategies for WebRTC

Tags: browser, webrtc, mdns

I can use mDNS feature by WebRTC by enabling `-enable-webrtc-hide-local-ips-with-mdns` flag at Google Chrome. But after a long investigation, I could not find a clear way for mDNS usage by WebRTC at other browsers such as Firefox or Edge.
Is there such a way to use mDNS while using WebRTC apps on browsers?

Thanks

Comment: Not yet, but I believe Safari use it?

Comment: I found that Chrome Canary M74 and Safari Technology Preview 74 now support local IP hiding using mDNS. The mDNS usage of browser-based WebRTC standards is shaping up over the draft document of 'Using Multicast DNS to protect privacy when exposing ICE candidates' which is co-authored by Google and Safari. It is not found any adaptation of other browsers about mDNS support for now.

Answer (score 5):

Firefox is currently working on adding support for mDNS here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1544770

Comment: Status update: mDNS support is going to come in Firefox 72.

Answer (score 4):

For firefox go to configuration `about:config` and set `media.peerconnection.ice.obfuscate_host_addresses` to `false` if this flag is true it will change local ip to `uuid`